# Second order combinatoric probabilities

Tags: combinations, probability, counting

Let say I have a set of symbols s = {a,b,c, ... } and a corpus1 :

```
a b g k.
o p a r b.
......
```

by simple counting I can calculate probabilities p(sym), p(sym1,sym2), p(sym1|sym2)

> will use upper-case for set S and CORPUS2 and PROBABILITIES related to them

now I create Set 'S' of all combinations of 's', S = { ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,... }, such that I create CORPUS2 from corpus1 in the following manner :

```
ab ag ak, bg bk, gk.
op oa or ob, pa pr pb, ar ab, rb.
......
```

i.e all pairs combinations, order does not matter ab == ba. Commas are for visual purpose.

My question : Is it possible to express probabilities P(SYM), P(SYM1,SYM2), P(SYM1|SYM2) via p(sym), p(sym1,sym2), p(sym1|sym2) i.e. have a formula

PS> In my thinking I'm stuck at the following dilema ...

```
  p(sym) = count(sym) / n
```

but to calculate P(SYM) w/o materializing CORPUS2 there seems to be no way, because it depends on p(sub-sym1),p(sub-sym2) multiplied by the lenght of the sequences they participate in. SYM = sub-sym1:sub-sym2

```
  may be :  ~P(SYM) = p(sub-sym1,sub-sym2) * p(sub-sym1) * p(sub-sym2) * avg-seq-len

  P(SYM) = for seq in corpus1 :
             total += ( len(seq) * (len(seq)+1)) / 2
             for sub-sym1 and sub-sym2 in combinations(seq,2) :
                if sub-sym1 and sub-sym2 == SYM :
                     count += 1 
           return count/total
```

there is a condition and hidden/random parameter/length involved ..

P(SYM1,SYM2), P(SYM1|SYM2) ??

---

Probabilities are defined/calculated in the usual way by counting .. for lower case symbols using corpus1 and for upper case symbols using CORPUS2.

Comment: How do you define `p(sym), p(sym1,sym2), p(sym1|sym2)` and `P(SYM), P(SYM1,SYM2), P(SYM1|SYM2)`?

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [maths.se]

Comment: updated ... by counting